# Get the position of an inline-block element

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to get the final position on screen of a div element part of a Svelte 4 component, which is instanced several times over the page.

I've been trying several ways, including that one, but I always get positions that are inconsistent with what I see on the screen. The first element, for example, returns a top position of more than 300px, even though the first element is visually on the top of the page.

Why is that, and how to get the proper position?

```html
<script>
import { onMount } from "svelte"
import { scale } from "svelte/transition"
import { quintIn } from "svelte/easing"
import { tick } from "svelte"

export let title
export let htmlContent = null

let positionCalculated = false
let windowDiv

onMount(async () => {
    await tick() // Wait for component to be loaded
    if (windowDiv && !positionCalculated) {
        // Add some random values to the position after div size is known and different from the previous ones
        const body = document.body
        const html = document.documentElement
        const scrollTop =
            window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0
        const scrollLeft =
            window.pageXOffset || html.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft || 0
        const box = windowDiv.getBoundingClientRect()
        const posTop = box.top + scrollTop
        const posLeft = box.left + scrollLeft
        console.log(
            `Initial position of ${title}: left: ${posLeft}, top: ${posTop}`,
        )
        positionCalculated = true
    }
})
</script>

<div
    class="window"
    bind:this={windowDiv}
    in:scale={{ duration: 500, easing: quintIn }}
>
    <h1 class="window-title">{title}</h1>
    {#if htmlContent}
        <div class="content">{@html htmlContent}</div>
    {/if}
</div>

<style>
    .window {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 250px;
        max-width: 600px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: What do you want the position for?

Comment: In order to add/substract a random number to the inline position.

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's a visual feature of the project. Those component need to have a random position centered on their natural inline position.

Comment: Then why aren't you applying this via CSS `transform`/`translate`?

Comment: That would need SCSS and we can't.

Comment: That does not follow at all.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you are talking about generating random values: That can still be done in JS and then passed e.g. as a CSS custom property to the element. You don't need SCSS for this.

Comment: We still need to get the initial position in order not too move the div outside of the screen. This is not completely random, it still needs to be centered on the natural inline position of the div.